# Local Apache Server mod_rewrite/pretty links issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wordpress

I've had to move from testing on the live server, to testing locally on a virtual apache server. I've installed XAMPP just fine, downloaded and installed the wordpress files and the database. Everything looks great! The local version of my homepage is identical to the live version. There's only one problem: the homepage is the *only* page that works. When I click on one of the links i.e. the "about" page (http://localhost/wordpress/about/), I am redirected to the xampp control panel (http://localhost/xampp).

I have a good feeling this has to do with a problem with the "pretty links"/mod_rewrite rules. I made sure I brought over the .htaccess file, and it contains the rewrite instructions. The wordpress database has the proper permalink structure, and the httpd.conf file has the "RewriteEngine on" and the "FollowSymLinks" directives enabled. There has got to be some sort of rewrite problem here, although I am not ruling out something else stupid I might have done. Thanks for all your help!

-E

*Here is what the .htaccess looks like:

`# BEGIN WordPress



RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

`#` END WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the httpd.conf, change the

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/app/wordpress"
```

also

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/path/to/your/app/wordpress">
```

This should work, the path is absolute.

Comment: This sounded like something I overlooked, so I changed it. Unfortunately, I still have this problem.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you restart your server after changing the configuration file ?

Comment: And also inside of the `<Directory "...">` directive you need to set `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the server and the AllowOverride is set to All.

Comment: I'm not sure what did it, but after resetting everything once more, it worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

And do you have load the:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in httpd.conf??

Answer (score 0):

If your server version works with a domain name, i.e: http://domainname.com is equivalent that http://localhost/wordpress the rewrite rules will be differents. post the rules here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that wordpress does not believe in relative paths for some reason. There is an assumption that wordpress is running from the server root not a directory under the root (e.g. `/var/www/wordpress` will not work, but `/var/www/` will).

The problem is with the .htaccess file they provide. It should re-write it to `index.php` and not `/index.php`. Change that line in your config and it will work.

What happens is that it tries to actually go to the default document root (in my case /var/www/index.php, which does not exist since I am using `http://localhost/worpress` which is an alias for `~/projects/worpress`). You can check your error log and it will tell you where it is trying to look for the index.php file (which will return a 404 error).

I can go on a rant about how stupid it is that they do that and how bad the whole software design of wordpress is. But I will spare you that :).